# Unite lists of named num in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am facing the problem that my results are in a confusing format after some calculations.  I have two different values calculated for every quarter of a year and stored **each value in a list** like the following output shows:

```
$`2015`
   1        2        3        4 
158.4567 165.7833 153.1233 140.8067 

$`2016`
       1        2        3        4 
140.4833 149.9200 157.9233 161.2467
```

My previous solutions ended up in something like `append(value1,value2)` that gives me the following not required output:

```
$`2015`
   1        2        3        4        1        2        3        4 
158.4567 165.7833 153.1233 140.8067 151.5633 155.2667 132.4667 128.4633 

$`2016`
       1        2        3        4        1        2        3        4 
140.4833 149.9200 157.9233 161.2467 127.8667 144.3600 150.8467 152.5333
```

I cannot find a way to unite those three lists to one list or dataframe that could be like:

```
date   value1     value2
2015.1 158.4567   151.5633
2015.2 165.7833   155.2667
2015.3 153.1233   132.4667
2015.4 140.8067   128.4633
2016.1 ...        ...
2016.2 ...        ...
2016.3 ...        ...
2016.4 ...        ...
```

**EDIT:**
Example Code that creates the two values i want to union in a dataframe:

```
library(lubridate) # for date operations

# manual created dataframe
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999-01-01 00:00:00'), as.Date('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), by="day"), 500)
dataM = data.frame("first" = 1:500, "sec" = c(1:500), "date"=date)

dataM <- transform(dataM, date = ymd(dataM$date)) # date to lubridate date format

  splitByYear = split(dataM, year(dataM$date))
  splitByQuarter = sapply(splitByYear, function(y) split(y, quarter(y$date)))

  a = sapply(splitByQuarter, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) max(y$date, na.rm = TRUE)))
  b = sapply(splitByQuarter, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) min(y$sec, na.rm = TRUE)))


  res = mapply(quarterPP, a,b)
  res

  quarterPP <- function(a, b){
    value1 = a+b
    value2 = b+1900

    c(value1, value2) # this should be in a dataframe
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach it by using `matrix` and `bind_rows` from `dplyr`,

```
#create dummy data
x <- setNames(rnorm(4), 1:4)
y <- setNames(rnorm(4), 1:4)
z <- setNames(rnorm(4), 1:4)
w <- setNames(rnorm(4), 1:4)
l1 <- list(`2015` = append(x, y), `2016` = append(z, w))

l1
#$`2015`
#         1          2          3          4          1          2          3           4 
#-0.0318981 -1.1241606 -0.1040653 -0.7819973 -0.8715601 -0.2287638 -0.9092943  -0.3757804 

#$`2016`
#         1          2          3          4          1          2          3           4 
#-0.6034540 -1.1469930  0.6085236  1.2565788 -0.1020582  0.1383716  1.1358109  -0.2635427 


l2 <- lapply(l1,function(i) { 
                  ind <- max(as.numeric(names(i))); 
                  data.frame(matrix(i, nrow = ind))
               })

final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(l2, .id = 'Year')
final_df$Year <- make.unique(final_df$Year)

final_df
#    Year         V1         V2
#1   2015 -0.0318981 -0.8715601
#2 2015.1 -1.1241606 -0.2287638
#3 2015.2 -0.1040653 -0.9092943
#4 2015.3 -0.7819973 -0.3757804
#5   2016 -0.6034540 -0.1020582
#6 2016.1 -1.1469930  0.1383716
#7 2016.2  0.6085236  1.1358109
#8 2016.3  1.2565788 -0.2635427
```

Another possibility with `spread` from `tidyr`,

```
l2 <- lapply(l1, function(i)setNames(tidyr::spread(transform(stack(i), grp=cumsum(ind == 1)), 
                          grp, values), c('ind', paste0('Value', 1:ceiling(length(i)/4)))))

bind_rows(l2, .id = 'Year')
```

Comment: Your answer works good for me. But i have the problem, that if at the beginning e.g. the first quarter is missing, i have NA values for all 4 quarters.

Comment: How do you mean? Can you show an example with the provided data?

Comment: i have added some example code. Your second possibility looks great, too. it works for one value perfectly, at the moment i am trying to implement this solution for two (or more values)

Answer (score 0):

If you combine all the lists into one, you can use `purrr::map_df` to iterate and coerce the results to a data.frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(47)

l1 <- set_names(replicate(3, set_names(rnorm(4), 1:4), simplify = FALSE), 2015:2017)
l2 <- set_names(replicate(3, set_names(rnorm(4), 1:4), simplify = FALSE), 2015:2017)

lst(l1, l2) %>%    # make a list, pulling names from objects
    map_df(~map_df(.x,    # for each sublist, iterate over it
                   ~data_frame(val = .x,    # making a data.frame of each subelement
                               quarter = as.integer(names(.x))), 
                   .id = 'year'),    # coercing the element to a data.frame with a column of names
           .id = 'var') %>%    # and coerce both elements to a data.frame with a column of names
    spread(var, val)    # finally, reshape to wide form

#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>     year quarter          l1          l2
#> *  <chr>   <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1   2015       1  1.99469634  0.49382018
#> 2   2015       2  0.71114251 -1.82822917
#> 3   2015       3  0.18540528  0.09147291
#> 4   2015       4 -0.28176501  0.67077922
#> 5   2016       1  0.10877555 -0.08107805
#> 6   2016       2 -1.08573747  1.26424109
#> 7   2016       3 -0.98548216 -0.70338819
#> 8   2016       4  0.01513086 -0.04057817
#> 9   2017       1 -0.25204590 -1.56616208
#> 10  2017       2 -1.46575030  0.24914817
#> 11  2017       3 -0.92245624 -0.34041599
#> 12  2017       4  0.03960243  0.41719084
```

Comment: With my data, i get the following error  Error: Variables must be length 1 or 1.
Problem variables: 'quarter'

Comment: That's coming from `data_frame` and likely telling you that some of your data doesn't have names as your example suggests (or are empty). You could recalculate the quarters with `quarter = seq_along(.x)`, but that's assuming that the vectors are always in order and only contain four values (both possibly false). To get a better answer, edit your question with the result of calling `dput(...)` on a representative subset of your data.